# Automation for acronym et al. with IEEEtran

Tags: citing, ieeetran

I use bibliographstyle `IEEEtran` and I am totally fine with the references in square brackets with numbers. I was wondering if there is a possibility to read in specific sections the name of the first author and create a reference like the following:

> Shelhamer et al. [7]

I am totally fine with creating a new command for this if something like this is not possible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "acronym et al" in the title of your posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you (a) load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers`, specify the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style (basically, it's the IEEEtran bib style optimized for use with `natbib`), and use `\citet` instructions (instead of the regular `\cite` instructions) to create the desired form of the citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{shelhamer, author = "Shelhamer and others", title = "Thoughts", year = 3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}

\begin{document}
\citet{shelhamer}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MaKaNu - Many thanks for this clarification. May I suggest we both delete our comments, as they're not particularly relevant for future readers of this posting? I've already gone ahead and deleted my earlier comments.